# Frontend deployment ASP.NET to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, gulp

I'm working with a frontend developer on a Mac ATM.

We do have a working setup where he can commit changes to CSS / cshtml files and so on to github and its automatically deployed to a deployment slot on Azure.

The major issue we are having is that everything is so slow. I could of course setup so that my frontend guy could upload files via FTP but the issue i have then is that my gulp task aren't running if he would make any changes to a CSS / LESS file or a JS file.

Is there any smart setup for this? For example that gulp could behave like it does locally and compile stuff when a file is changed. Or that you could do some sort of custom deployment where we do not build the project if there are only changes to none compiled files or something. Can i for example execute gulp task manually in Azure? I only find loads of articles on how to do it during deployment.

Or is there any ways to speed up the local -> github -> azure deployment process in general?

Sorry for so may questions in one post :)

Comment: "everything is so slow", please elaborate.

Comment: what azure service are you using? are you using App Services?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about this. But the process from pushing to GitHub and the final deployment on my Azue AppService takes a while (like 3-10 min).